# Как правильно: трейсбек или трейсбэк... или как-то еще?

Tags: орфография, заимствования

В последнее время появилась калька с английского `traceback`. Есть несколько ее вариантов:

- Трейсбек
- Трейсбэк
- Трэйсбек

...и прочие в том же духе.

А как все-таки правильней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***трейсбек.***

В таком варианте слово закрепилось в русском языке, хотя произношение гласного твердое.

Дело в том, что уже существует слова  **[трейс](https://dis.net/index.php/tekhpodderzhka/statji/83-chto-takoe-aj-pi-mak-adres-ping-i-trejs#:%7E:text=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE,%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE)**  – маршрут и приставка  **[бек](https://neftyanik27.ru/chto-oznachaet/cto-oznacaet-pristavka-bek)**